How to aggregate JSON data as expected?
I have response text from API as below, I want aggregate them to new format response. But it is quite difficult, please help me (using JavaScript)
Response from API:
[
  {
    sumTime: "2024-04-25 12:00:00",
    equipParaName: "P1",
    sumValue: 5
  },
  {
    sumTime: "2024-04-25 05:00:00",
    equipParaName: "P2",
    sumValue: 10,
  },
  {
    sumTime: "2024-04-25 09:00:00",
    equipParaName: "P1",
    sumValue: 8
  },
  {
    sumTime: "2024-04-25 08:00:00",
    equipParaName: "P2",
    sumValue: 3,
  },
  {
    sumTime: "2024-04-25 08:00:00",
    equipParaName: "P3",
    sumValue: 12,
  }
]

Conditions:

With same sumTime, the equipParaName can not be duplicated

If have 3 unique equipParaName, the expecting result has maximum 3 attributes belongs to them in one object

Same equipParaName in result list must order by sumTime ASC
equipParaName: P1, sumTime: 2024-04-25 12:00:00, sumValue: 5
equipParaName: P1, sumTime: 2024-04-25 09:00:00, sumValue: 8
==> The sumTime 2024-04-25 09:00:00 should be added to 1st object and sumTime: 2024-04-25 12:00:00 added to 2nd object in result list



Expect:
[
  {
    index: 1,
    P1: 8,
    P1_sumTime: "2024-04-25 09:00:00",
    P2: 10,
    P2_sumTime: "2024-04-25 05:00:00",
    P3: 12,
    P3_sumTime: "2024-04-25 07:00:00"
  },
  {
    index: 2,
    P1: 5,
    P1_sumTime: "2024-04-25 12:00:00",
    P2: 3,
    P2_sumTime: "2024-04-25 08:00:00"
  }
]


you forgot the section called "code that I tried" :p you also fail to disclose where the value of index comes from

i guess your P3 in the first output item contains invalid sumTime


group items by equipParaName and sort by sumTime
collect items into the final group objects so there's only unique equipParaName in an object.



const input=[{sumTime:"2024-04-25 12:00:00",equipParaName:"P1",sumValue:5},{sumTime:"2024-04-25 05:00:00",equipParaName:"P2",sumValue:10},{sumTime:"2024-04-25 09:00:00",equipParaName:"P1",sumValue:8},{sumTime:"2024-04-25 08:00:00",equipParaName:"P2",sumValue:3},{sumTime:"2024-04-25 08:00:00",equipParaName:"P3",sumValue:12}];

const ps = input.reduce((r, item) => ((r[item.equipParaName] ??= []).push(item), r), {});
const result = Array.from({length: Math.max(...Object.values(ps).map(arr => arr.length))}, (_, i) => ({index:i+1}));
Object.keys(ps).sort().forEach(key => 
   ps[key].sort((a,b) => (a = a.sumTime, b = b.sumTime, a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0))
    .forEach(({sumTime, sumValue}, i) => (result[i][key] = sumValue, result[i][key + '_sumTime'] = sumTime))
);

console.log(result);
.as-console-wrapper{
max-height:100% !important;
}



